# jhipster 8: What is the right/recommended way of reindexing ElasticSearch?

Tags: jhipster

I'm using jhipster 8, enabled ElasticSearch. I'm still in the dev profile and I'm still cycling through generating the app. When starting the application, it doesn't reindex ElasticSearch, so the preloaded fake data cannot be searched until an entity is updated.

I find a couple of reindexing apps, but they are outdated and don't work for me. Is there a new way of triggering the reindexing? Am I asking a wrong question? Unfortunately the jhipster documentation doesn't elaborate on this.

I'm running ElasticSearch in docker. Tried generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer and generator-jhipster-es-entity-reindexer. Both are throwing errors when run.

Basically, I'm expecting jhipster documentation on the issue of reindexing. I think, it is necessary during development and testing.

Comment: I was able to use the reindexer module with JHipster 7 after making the changes in this PR: https://github.com/Ebsan/generator-jhipster-es-entity-reindexer/pull/8